# Read, Search & Sort all CSV values without the dupes

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have the following CSV:

```
Title, Rating, Year, Genre
All Quiet on the Western Front,8.1,1930,"Drama , War"
Gone with the Wind,8.2,1939,"Drama , Romance , War"
The Wizard of Oz,8.2,1939,"Adventure , Family , Fantasy , Musical"
Fantasia,7.9,1940,"Animation , Family , Fantasy , Music"
Pinocchio,7.6,1940,"Animation , Adventure , Drama , Family , Fantasy , Music"
The Great Dictator,8.5,1940,"Comedy , Drama , War"
Citizen Kane,8.5,1941,"Drama , Mystery"
Dumbo,7.3,1941,"Animation , Family , Musical"
Bambi,7.4,1942,"Animation , Drama , Family"
Casablanca,8.7,1942,"Drama , Romance , War"
It's a Wonderful Life,8.7,1946,"Drama , Family , Fantasy"
Notorious,8.2,1946,"Drama , Film-Noir , Romance , Thriller"
All About Eve,8.4,1950,Drama
Cinderella,7.3,1950,"Animation , Family , Fantasy , Musical , Romance"
Alice in Wonderland,7.4,1951,"Animation , Adventure , Family , Fantasy , Musical"
Strangers on a Train,8.2,1951,"Crime , Film-Noir , Thriller"
Dial M for Murder,8.2,1954,"Crime , Thriller"
Knock on Wood,7,1954,Comedy
Seven Samurai,8.8,1954,"Action , Drama"
Lady and the Tramp,7.4,1955,"Animation , Adventure , Comedy , Family , Romance"
Rebel Without a Cause,7.8,1955,"Drama , Romance"
The Trouble with Harry,7.2,1955,"Comedy , Mystery"
Forbidden Planet,7.7,1956,"Action , Adventure , Sci-Fi"
The Ten Commandments,7.9,1956,"Adventure , Drama , History"
12 Angry Men,8.9,1957,Drama
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this (My head is not working correctly right now):

Read the CSV and create an array that only shows all unique Genre (eg: Drama, War, Fantasy.. without repeating the Genre in the array)

Search the CSV for rows that have a specific Genre. For example, if I search for Drama, only rows that have the Drama value in the 4th column will be shown. (without showing the Genre column)

Sort the CSV by either Title, Rating or Year (without showing the Genre column).

I am reading the CSV in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "movies.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            var results = $.parse(data);
        }
     });
```

If I do a `alert(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))` it will print the correct information. The JSON Object looks like this:

```
{
  "results": {
    "fields": [
      "Title",
      " Rating",
      " Year",
      " Genre"
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "Title": "All Quiet on the Western Front",
        " Rating": 8.1,
        " Year": 1930,
        " Genre": "Drama , War"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Gone with the Wind",
        " Rating": 8.2,
        " Year": 1939,
        " Genre": "Drama , Romance , War"
      },
      {
        "Title": "The Wizard of Oz",
        " Rating": 8.2,
        " Year": 1939,
        " Genre": "Adventure , Family , Fantasy , Musical"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Fantasia",
        " Rating": 7.9,
        " Year": 1940,
        " Genre": "Animation , Family , Fantasy , Music"
```

So I know that part is working. I am trying to create an array and then fill a SELECT tag with the Genre values. Then if the user selects one of them, it will search the file again but only showing the rows that have the Genre specify. The user will be able to sort the list by the 3 first columns. My asking right now since my head (and eyesight) is not working very good right now.

Comment: Can you provide your JSON object?

Comment: JavaScript should not be used to handle CSVs, unless you want to run crazy regular expressions on everything. You should use PHP's `fgetcsv()` with AJAX, including more information in your `url`, if you're using the `get` method.

Comment: Have you tried a JSON query package? http://orangevolt.blogspot.com/2012/12/8-ways-to-query-json-structures.html I'm partial to linq.js myself

Comment: I know how to do this in PHP and Python, what I need right now is to do it with either Javascript or JQuery alone (without PHP or Python).

Comment: @Arithmomaniac is Jsonsql for real?? or is it April fools?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Why would it be a joke? Click through, and you'll find actual source: http://www.trentrichardson.com/jsonsql/scripts/jsonsql-0.1.js

Comment: @Arithmomaniac because it's like the most amazing thing ever that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The genre select**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/4N676/25/

```
var movies = new Movies(JSON.parse(gists.files.Movies.content));
var html = '<option>Filter by genre</option>';

movies.getGenres().forEach(function(genre) {

    html += '<option value="' + genre + '">' + genre + '</option>';
});

$('#genre')
    .html(html)
    .change(function() {

        var list = movies
            .reset()
            .filterByGenre(this.value)
            .sortByTitleAsc()
            .getList();

        alert(JSON.stringify(list));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/4N676/

**Base**

```
var Movies = function(movies)
{
    var genres = [];
    var ratingMin = Infinity;
    var ratingMax = -1;
    var yearMin = Infinity;
    var yearMax = -1;

    movies.forEach(function(movie, movieIndex) {

        movie.Genre  = movie.Genre.split(', ');
        movie.Rating = parseFloat(movie.Rating);
        movie.Year = parseInt(movie.Year, 10);

        ratingMin = Math.min(movie.Rating, ratingMin);
        ratingMax = Math.max(movie.Rating, ratingMax);

        yearMin = Math.min(movie.Year, yearMin);
        yearMax = Math.max(movie.Year, yearMax);

        movie.Genre.forEach(function(genre, genreIndex) {

            genre = $.trim(genre).toLowerCase();
            movie.Genre[genreIndex] = genre;

            if (genres.indexOf(genre) < 0) {

                genres.push(genre);
            }

            genres.sort();
        });
    });

    this.original  = movies;
    this.list      = movies.slice();
    this.ratingMin = ratingMin;
    this.ratingMax = ratingMax;
    this.yearMin   = yearMin;
    this.yearMax   = yearMax;
    this.genres    = genres;
};

Movies.prototype.reset = function()
{
    this.list = this.original.slice();

    return this;
};
```

**Getters**

```
Movies.prototype.getList = function()
{
    return this.list.slice();
};

Movies.prototype.getRatingRange = function()
{
    return [this.ratingMin, this.ratingMax];
};

Movies.prototype.getRatingMax = function()
{
    return this.ratingMax;
};

Movies.prototype.getRatingMin = function()
{
    return this.ratingMin;
};

Movies.prototype.getYearRange = function()
{
    return [this.yearMin, this.yearMax];
};

Movies.prototype.getYearMax = function()
{
    return this.yearMax;
};

Movies.prototype.getYearMin = function()
{
    return this.yearMin;
};

Movies.prototype.getGenres = function()
{
    return this.genres.slice();
};
```

**Filters**

```
Movies.prototype.filterByNumbers = function(property, number)
{
    if ($.isNumeric(number)) {

        this.list = this.list.filter(function(movie) {

            return movie[property] === number;
        });
    }

    if ($.isArray(number)) {

        this.list = this.list.filter(function(movie) {

            return movie[property] >= number[0]
                && movie[property] <= number[1];
        });
    }

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.filterByGenre = function(genre)
{
    this.list = this.list.filter(function(movie) {

        return movie
            .Genre
            .indexOf(genre.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.filterByTitle = function(title)
{
    this.list = this.list.filter(function(movie) {

        return movie
            .Title
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(title.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.filterByYear = function(year)
{ 
    this.filterByNumbers('Year', year);

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.filterByRating = function(rating)
{ 
    this.filterByNumbers('Rating', rating);

    return this;
};
```

**Sorters**

```
Movies.prototype.sortAsc = function(property)
{ 
    this.list.sort(function(a, b) {

        return a[property] > b[property];
    });

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.sortDesc = function(property)
{ 
    this.list.sort(function(a, b) {

        return a[property] < b[property];
    });

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.sortByTitleAsc = function()
{ 
    this.sortAsc('Title');

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.sortByTitleDesc = function()
{ 
    this.sortDesc('Title');

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.sortByYearAsc = function()
{ 
    this.sortAsc('Year');

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.sortByYearDesc = function()
{ 
    this.sortDesc('Year');

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.sortByRatingAsc = function()
{ 
    this.sortAsc('Rating');

    return this;
};

Movies.prototype.sortByRatingDesc = function()
{ 
    this.sortDesc('Rating');

    return this;
};
```

**Usage**

```
$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/gists/9803182', function(gists) {

    var movies = new Movies(JSON.parse(gists.files.Movies.content));

    movies
        .filterByGenre('comedy')
        .filterByYear([1954, 2000])
        .sortByTitleDesc();

    console.log('Filtered and sorted', movies.getList());
    console.log('Original', movies.reset().getList());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here it goes.

You can parse your JSON and traverse through it one by one. You would need to have a parent object which would keep your final rows vs. genre values.

The parent object would look something like this:

```
var myObject = {
genre : {records: []}
}
```

This will contain genre to records mapping.

While traversing the JSON object, if you find the genre already in your 'myObject', just push the record. If not, create the 'genre' and then push it.

Something like the below.

```
//Initialize my variables - Note, I'm using my own JSON
var objectArray = JSON.parse('[{"title":"title1","name":"name1","genre":"genre1"},{"title":"title2","name":"name2","genre":"genre2"},{"title":"title3","name":"name3","genre":"genre1"}]'),
counter=0,myObject={};

for (count=0; counter<objectArray.length; counter++) {
    var individualRecord=objectArray[counter];
    if(myObject[individualRecord.genre] === undefined) {
        console.log('creating object');
        myObject[individualRecord.genre]={records : []};
    }
    console.log('adding individual record');
    myObject[individualRecord.genre].records.push(individualRecord);
}
```

console.log(myObject) will give you:

```
genre1 - Array with 2 elements
genre2 - Array with 1 element
```

Post this if you want to retrieve elements for a particular genre, you could just do this:

```
myObject["genre1"] - to handle dynamic genres

OR 

myObject.genre1 - to explicitly fetch the value of the variable
```

Once you have the data stored in this format, you would not need to read the file again. You can filter based on `myObject["<filter 1>"]`, etc..

Hope this helps!